# Even basic command not working on cygwin

Tags: cygwin

I just installed cygwin & i am unable to do basic commands in cygwing like :-

```
$ ls -l
total 0

$ ls | wc -l
0

$ ls -ld
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 Shivendra Gupta None 0 Oct 10 14:40
```

Comment: That's valid output when run in an empty directory or a directory with only hidden files.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ..i can understand but i want to practice these commands & i dont know why it is empty directory.. cygwin is installed in C directory ..i am completely noob so plz elaborate if you can.

Comment: I got this:      $ pwd
/home/Shivendra Gupta

Comment: If you want to list the content of the `C:\ ` windows directory, that's `ls /cygdrive/c`. If you want to see hidden files in the current directory, it's `ls -lA`

Comment: @ Stephane Chazelas  u got me ...thank you so much.. it worked ..you rocks !!

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong per se with the output you posted.

Should you expect to see the usual `.` and `..` entries, you have to enable hidden files display. To do so, use `ls -la` instead of `ls -l`.

If you just opened a Cygwin terminal right after installing you will see that you have several other hidden files there, such as `.profile` for example, as `.` at the beginning of a filename means "hidden".

Anyway, should you need to urgently dig into Cygwin, there's one place to go: [its official documentation](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net.html).

Comment: Thanks bro ..i get following output now                                                      
$ ls -la
total 25
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 Shivendra Gupta None    0 Oct 10 14:40 .
drwxrwxrwt+ 1 Shivendra Gupta None    0 Oct  3 22:18 ..
-rw-------  1 Shivendra Gupta None  358 Oct 10 14:40 .bash_history
-rwxr-xr-x  1 Shivendra Gupta None 1494 Oct  3 22:18 .bash_profile
-rwxr-xr-x  1 Shivendra Gupta None 6054 Oct  3 22:18 .bashrc
-rwxr-xr-x  1 Shivendra Gupta None 1919 Oct  3 22:18 .inputrc
-rwxr-xr-x  1 Shivendra Gupta None 1236 Oct  3 22:18 .profile

Comment: @johnkumar Makes sense, you are in your home directory.

Comment: ..ok i got that i am in home directory but what to do next if i have to practice the basic commands of unix through cygwin

Comment: @johnkumar This is way beyond the original question. The best is to search for some tutorials on the internet, and to have a look at the documentation I linked.

Comment: definitely @Shlublu